# Unity lens to search for tags

Tags: unity, nautilus, application-development, lenses, tracker

I want to develop a dash lens to search files by tags (the ones that are set through Nautilus). I know on the one hand this program, that does the search:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/tracker-tag.1.html

But, other than that, I don't know where to start. Where can I learn how to do it? I have a good knowledge of C/C++ and Linux/POSIX, but I never developed for a graphical interface and less than anything for Unity. I also would want an opinion about the "tags" option in Nautilus, is it there to stay? I wouldn't want to develop something that is doomed next version. And finally, if I get it to work, how can I make it public for others to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Most of your questions should be answered by looking at the [developer pages of ubuntu](http://developer.ubuntu.com).

Especially:

1. "I dont' know where to start":  http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/
2. "Where can I learn how to do it": http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/
3. "I never developed [...] anything for Unity": http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/platform/unity/ especially http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/lenses-and-scopes/
4. "tag option in Nautilus": I have no idea if this is to stay, but I cant find plans to remove it: https://live.gnome.org/Nautilus/Roadmap
5. "Make it public": http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/

As an additional note: you probably should have a look at "tracker-tags", a nautilus extension for tracker-tag support.

Comment: I began to study how to do a Unity lens, however what's worrying me is question 4: are tags staying? On the one hand, Nautilus nowadays does not seem very stable. Features go with a whim every month. Last thing I read has it that Ubuntu is thinking on what to do with Nautilus because of this unpredictability. On the other hand, tags themselves seem to be partially broken on 12.04: you can edit them from the "Properties" dialog box, but not from the "Tags" dialog box.

Comment: Finally, the tracker-tags extension seems lost or unmaintained, could not find a decent source for it, and I did find a lot of complaints about it not working anymore. Tags were a thing in 2007, and now nobody seems to care about it, when it is something really useful: I saw a lot of people asking about such functionality